# Why use EventArgs.Empty instead of null?

Tags: c#, events, eventargs

I recall reading, on multiple occasions and in multiple locations, that when firing the typical event:

```
protected virtual OnSomethingHappened()
{
    this.SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

e should be EventArgs.Empty if there are no interesting event args, not null.

I've followed the guidance in my code, but I realized that I'm not clear on why that's the preferred technique. Why does the stated contract prefer     EventArgs.Empty over null?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe the reasoning behind the NOT NULL is that when passed as a parameter, it is not expected for the method to need to potentially handle a null reference exception.

If you pass null, and the method tries to do something with e it will get a null reference exception, with EventArgs.Empty it will not.

Comment: In what situations would you use a similar technique in your own code?

Comment: If one method might pass event information and another might not.  I can still call e.ToString() regardless, but one might pass a custom type and the other passes EventArgs.Empty

Comment: Greg, the whole point here is that the event handler is *not* your code. You want safety first here because you are defining and raising the event, and somebody else will write the event handler.

Comment: There are conventions and norms, if not guarantees, around events. One is the EventArgs should *never* be null and the handler should not have to check for it.

Answer (score 28):

`EventArgs.Empty` is an instance of the [Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Basically, having an object representing "no value" to avoid checking for null when using it.

Answer (score 8):

I believe `EventArgs.Empty` is used to maintain the convention of passing an argument with an event, even if none are needed.

Mitchel Sellers posted the other half of my reason halfway through my post: it prevents a null reference exception should a method try and do something with that argument (besides check if it is null).

`EventArgs.Empty`  basically does the work of a globally defined Event Argument with no additional information.

To give a similar example of maintaining a convention, our team  uses `string.Empty` to initialize a string because otherwise different coders might use `newString = ""; or newString = " "; or newString = null;`, all of which may produce different results for different check conditions.

A (slightly pedantic) reason to use `EventArgs.Empty` vs `new EventArgs()` is that the former does not initialize a new `EventArgs`, saving a slight amount of memory.

Comment: The "slight amount of memory" might be significant for an event that is raised many times, like a MouseMove event.

Comment: Doesn't EventArgs.Empty return an reference to an new instance of EventArgs? So where does the memory saving come from?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a general-purpose method which has the `EventHandler` signature that's called from any event handler and is passed both the *`object sender`* and *`EventArgs e`*, it can call `e.ToString()`, e.g., for logging events, without worrying about a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I used long time "new EventArgs()" instead of "EventArgs.Empty"... I think the important is to pass something that will not cause an Null exception.

Comment: EventArgs.Empty isn't null, it's a static variable initialized with "new EventArgs()". It means you don't end up wasting resources initializing what is effectively a placeholder object with no varying value.

Comment: If there is no meaningful data in the EventArgs, don't instantiate one. EventArgs.Empty will do the job without the overhead of creating a useless object which will only be garbage collected.

Comment: I agree. Using new EventArgs() makes the intent less clear to the next programmer who comes along, and it's slightly wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

from Albahari book: `"in order to avoid unnecessarily instantiating an instance of EventArgs."`

Comment: `null` doesn't instantiate an instance of `EventArgs`.