# Can not use string in another method

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver
    {
        Url = filename
    };
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    Watcher_Changed(driver);
}

private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    driver.navigate().refresh(); // Can not use driver
}
```

I tried to use `driver` in another method using the above code but it does not work, what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm not sure but you can try using this

1. define driver in global scope

What you are doing is defining and declaring **driver** variable inside the
scope of button click.so,it will not be accessible from any other method...

2. Secondly,if you are making a function call within the button click event then use its function parameters.
   Like in watcher_changed method you can try using this

> assuming you are calling watcher_changed function as watcher_changed(driver,"")
> else it will give you error

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace MyStuff
    {
        public class MyClass : Page
        {
            **`define your IwebDriver here`**

           public void MyButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               **access IwebDriver here**
           }

           private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
           {
               sender.navigate().refresh(); // Can not use driver
           }
         
       }
    }
```

Comment: There is no "global scope" in C#.

Comment: I mean to say outside the button click event method

Comment: Could you please clean up your answer? The formatting is terrible. It's hard to read like it is.

Comment: using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyStuff
{
    public class MyClass : Page
    {
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label MyLabel;
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button MyButton;
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox MyTextBox;
**// define your IWebDriver here**
        public void MyButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyLabel.Text = MyTextBox.Text.ToString();
        }
    }
}

Comment: What's that? Please don't put code in comments - edit your answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

You create `driver` as a local variable inside a method, this will only be accessible inside this method. To be a little more precise it is actually visible in the `scope` it is defined in, you should definitely read on that.

To make `driver` accessible to all functions you should either pass it around or better create it inside of the class your methods are in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sender`. Something like this:

```
private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    var driver = sender as IWebDriver;//Or sender as ChromeDriver
    driver.navigate().refresh(); 
}
```

You need however  specify the `FileSystemEventArgs` as your second parameter. For example:

```
Watcher_Changed(driver , null);
```

Comment: @rene I have passed the `null` as it's second parameter, just to make the code compile-able.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, how can I specify that driver is a new ChromeDriver as well using your code?

Comment: @S.Akbari you can pass `EventArgs.Empty` too there, it is preferable read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188692/why-use-eventargs-empty-instead-of-null)

Comment: @Daniell use `ChromeDriver` like this `var driver = sender as ChromeDriver;`

Comment: I cant seem to combine this to create the sender `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver`

Comment: @Daniell I guess you didn't use the `sender` inside the `Watcher_Changed`. See my updated answer...